# RSA Security In Asp.net MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am testing RSA secureID(Token) to use for security in my asp.net mvc project.
It protects the url that i assigned and it will prompt to insert 
UserName and password when we browse that url.
For eg,if we assigned `**Http://SamlpleApp/Sales/main.aspx**` to protect,
RSA will prompt to set username and password when we browse it.
That one is working properly in normal asp.net projects.

But,i don't know 
how to use in my asp.net mvc prj,i want to protect one view,physical 
address may be `**Http://SampleApp/Views/Sales/Index.aspx**` ,but we have to call the 
controller index action first and that wil redirect to view in mvc.

So,is it possible 
to get physical url of view like "`Http://SampleApp/Views/Sales/Index.aspx`" 
when we browse controller action? I mean i want to get that url when we call 
controller action.
Please give me the the right way.

Best Regards,
Indi

Comment: An URL in MVC *doesn't correspond to a View* - it *corresponds to an Action*. So what RSA lets your protect here is an *Action* in your application. With this in mind, the solution should be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to go directly to the view. If you look in the web.config file in your Views directory, you will notice it blocks all requests.

If you want to secure a page you have to do it by securing the controller or the action by using the authorize attribute (or implement your own authorisation).